# ArchUnitTest not running as expected

Tags: .net, automated-tests, .net-7.0, archunit

Could anyone say why am I getting these errors, given the configurations below?

```
Message: 
  ArchUnitNET.xUnit.FailedArchRuleException : "Classes that are Classes that are Classes that implement 'IRequest' and are not abstract and have name matching ".+Command$" and have name matching ".+Command$" should reside in namespace with full name matching ".+\.Commands\."" failed:
    Core.Application.MasterDataSync.Commands.SynchronizeMasterDataCommand does reside in Core.Application.MasterDataSync.Commands
    Core.Application.ManagerChain.Commands.CalculateManagerChainCommand does reside in Core.Application.ManagerChain.Commands
    Core.Application.EmployeeSync.Commands.SynchronizeEmployeeCommand does reside in Core.Application.EmployeeSync.Commands
    Core.Application.EmployeeFixedPaymentSummaries.Commands.SynchronizeLatestYearlyPaymentsCommand does reside in Core.Application.EmployeeFixedPaymentSummaries.Commands
```

Getting the assemblies:

```
using System.Reflection;
using ArchUnitNET.Domain;
using ArchUnitNET.Loader;
using Assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly;

namespace Corsica.Tests.ArchUnit;

public static class Corsica
{
    public static readonly Architecture ARCHITECTURE =
        new ArchLoader()
            .LoadAssemblies(GetSolutionAssemblies())
            .Build();

    private static Assembly[] GetSolutionAssemblies()
    {
        var assemblies = Directory
            .GetFiles(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "*.dll")
            .Select(x => Assembly.Load(AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(x)))
            .Where(x => x.FullName!.StartsWith("Core"));
        return assemblies.ToArray();
    }
}
```

The classes:

```
using MediatR;

namespace Core.Application.EmployeeFixedPaymentSummaries.Commands;
public class SynchronizeLatestYearlyPaymentsCommand : IRequest { }

using MediatR;

namespace Core.Application.EmployeeSync.Commands;

public class SynchronizeEmployeeCommand : IRequest { }

using MediatR;

namespace Core.Application.MasterDataSync.Commands;

public class SynchronizeMasterDataCommand : IRequest
{
}

using MediatR;

namespace Core.Application.ManagerChain.Commands;

public class CalculateManagerChainCommand : IRequest { }
```

The test class, which defines the rules that should supposedly pass.

```
using ArchUnitNET.Domain;
using ArchUnitNET.xUnit;
using MediatR;
using static ArchUnitNET.Fluent.ArchRuleDefinition;

namespace Corsica.Tests.ArchUnit;

public class Cqrs
{
    private static readonly IObjectProvider<IType> NON_ABSTRACT_CLASSES_IMPLEMENTING_IREQUEST =
            Classes()
                .That().AreAssignableTo(typeof(IRequest<>)).Or().AreAssignableTo(typeof(IRequest)).As("Classes that implement 'IRequest'")
                .And().AreNotAbstract()
                .And().HaveName(".+Command$", true);

    private static readonly IObjectProvider<IType> COMMANDS =
        Classes().That().Are(NON_ABSTRACT_CLASSES_IMPLEMENTING_IREQUEST)
            .And().HaveName(".+Command$", true);

    private static readonly IObjectProvider<IType> QUERIES =
        Classes().That().Are(NON_ABSTRACT_CLASSES_IMPLEMENTING_IREQUEST)
            .And().HaveName(".+Query$", true);

    [Fact]
    public void ClassesInheritingFromIRequestShouldHaveNameEndingWithCommandOrQuery()
    {
        Classes().That().Are(NON_ABSTRACT_CLASSES_IMPLEMENTING_IREQUEST)
            .Should().HaveName(".+(Command|Query)$", true).As("should have names ending with 'Command' or 'Query'")
            .Check(Corsica.ARCHITECTURE);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void CommandsShouldResideInCommandsNamespace()
    {
        Classes().That().Are(COMMANDS)
            .Should().ResideInNamespace(".+\\.Commands\\.", true)
            .Check(Corsica.ARCHITECTURE);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void QueriesShouldResideInQueriesNamespace()
    {
        Classes().That().Are(QUERIES)
            .Should().ResideInNamespace(".+\\.Queries\\.", true)
            .Check(Corsica.ARCHITECTURE);
    }

}
```

I wasn't expecting any errors. And it runs for the entire project, but only raises the error for those classes I mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example is working for me using

```
Classes().That().Are(COMMANDS).Should().ResideInNamespace(".+\\.Commands(\\.|$)", true).Check(Architecture);
```

This is, allow "Commands" to be at the end or inside the namespace.

(This would have been a comment on your post if I had the rep :) )